# How can I fill the area underneath a line in a graph made using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a graph made using Canvas that can plot functions. I would like to be able to turn these functions into inequalities by shading the regions above or below them. My best guess is that it would have something to do with context.fill() but I have no idea how I would implement that.

http://jsfiddle.net/WFugJ/504/

Here's the portion of the code specific to the equations that I'm hoping to turn into inequalities:

```
  myGraph.drawEquation(function(x) {
    return 5 * Math.sin(x);
  }, 'black', 3);

  myGraph.drawEquation(function(x) {
    return x * x;
  }, 'blue', 1);

  myGraph.drawEquation(function(x) {
    return 1 * x;
  }, 'red', 1);
```

(Side note: If someone could help me add dotted gridlines, that would likewise be helpful.)

Thanks in advance!